# Cannot knit to html_output when dev = 'svg' and labs include an expression

Tags: r, grid, r-markdown, knitr

I'm generating an html_output from a .Rmd file in R. Specifically, I want the output `ggplot2` images to be saved as .svg files, but get the resulting error:

```
Quitting from lines 28-47 (reprex.Rmd) 
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  Metric information not available for this family/device
Calls: <Anonymous> ... drawDetails -> drawDetails.text -> grid.Call.graphics
Execution halted
```

I think I've identified where the problem occurs in the code (see commented line from the code below), but am not sure what to do about it other than submit a bug report to the Rmarkdown folks. What I think is happening is that the expression `labs(x = expression(T[i]~-~T[A]~"(°C)"))` is causing the error due to the subscripts. That is, if I remove this line of code, or change it to `labs(x = "Ti -Ta (°C))` then the error no longer exists.

Here is a reproducible example that creates the error:

````
---
title: "Reprex"
output:
  html_document
---

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = TRUE,
  dev = "svg"
  )

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data("mtcars")

#Inset
inset <- mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(hp, mpg, color = cyl)) +
  geom_point()
inset <- ggplotGrob(inset)

#Main
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = expression(T[i]~-~T[A]~"(°C)")) + #This seems to be the problem spot.
  annotation_custom(inset, xmin = 22.5, xmax = 34.5, ymin = 3.5, ymax = 5.5)
```
````

Has anyone run into this problem? I'm running R v3.5.3 and all my packages are up-to-date with that version.

Comment: Have you tried setting an explicit value for `fig.width` in the chunk or knitr options?

Comment: Hi @user2554330, thanks for your response. In my original code I did have explit `fig.width` values, but I tried to simplify for the reproducible example. I just tried it with `fig.width=8`, but get the same error. What were you thinking was going on with that suggestion?

Comment: You may try the dev version of **knitr** on Github: https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation Your issue might have been fixed by a recent PR: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/pull/1705

Comment: @JasonMercer:  I thought that "metric information is not available" might be helped by that.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue using R 3.5.3 for Windows 10, and knitr 1.22.8 (as installed from XRAN, as suggested by @YihuiXie) above. My only fix for now is to remove the expressions from the labs.

Comment: The problem might be unique to Windows... I cannot reproduce it on macOS with either knitr 1.22 from CRAN or 1.22.8 from Github. I'm not an expert of grid graphics or graphical devices, so I'm afraid I cannot offer any further help. Sorry.

Comment: @FMKerckhof, thanks for looking into the problem with the dev version of **knitr**.

Comment: @YihuiXie, thanks for looking into the issue on a Unix-like OS. Do you think it worth providing this example to the R Core Team, since grid seems to be a base priority package? That sounds super intimidating.

Comment: If you want to report to R core, you have to make a minimal example to illustrate the issue with only base R; the example shouldn't involve knitr. The problem is that unless you are very familiar with how **knitr** works, it would be very challenging for you to make such a minimal example (and I don't have time to make one for you, unfortunately).

Comment: Well thank you for at least clearing that up for me @YihuiXie.

Comment: I have tried the problematic windows code on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, with a cairo-capable R3.6.0 install. There, I could also not reproduce the issue (even with CRAN knitr 1.22). So clearly it is windows-specific. However, I did have to adjust my `.Rprofile` to make sure that indeed `cairo` rather than Xlib was used. I am not sure, but maybe having cairo graphics on windows could help there?